# How to secure API Key and AppID to be intercepted in middle?

Tags: android, ssl, https, charles-proxy

I am creating a mobile app and this app uses some third parties. These third parties are connected using API Keys and AppIDs.

Is it possible to intercept the HTTPS request of a live android App using some tools like  **Charles proxy** or **Proxyman**?

We can intercept debug build easily, If production app could not be intercepted then why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to intercept the production build because there is no official way to add Trust Config to the bundled app.

However, if you have a Root Android Device, you could do it by force the device trust Proxyman in Trust Store at `/system/etc/security/cacerts/`

Quick tutorial: https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/android-device#ssl-proxying-using-root-device